# php regex matching unicode don't work with older versions of php

Tags: php, regex, unicode, version

I matches a word starting with a unicode charachter using PHP

the code is

```
<?php 

$word='üzgün';
$article='i düzgün you ';
if (preg_match('/\b'.$word.'\b/u', $article)) {
    echo 'matchs';
} else {
    echo 'nomatch';
}
phpinfo();

?>
```

it gives 'nomatch' which is fine it works with my PHP 5.4

but at some customers sites their servers php version are 5.2

the same code gives match

I tried the code myself on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

and got the different results for the different versions

what should I do regarding this ?  any work around or this was a bug got fixed and I have no choice ?

Comment: On what condition do you get `matchs` ? When the word is identical to the article?

Comment: It may have something to do with the encoding of the file -- are you sure the file is UTF-8 encoded? Also, look at the preg_quote function and be sure to compare the preg_match to `=== false` or `!== false` b/c sometimes it will return values which equate to false.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Preg_quote didn't help ,  comparing to false didn't work also

Comment: @DainisAbols it gives matches on 5.2 which should give nomatch

Comment: @Atef - I didn't think those 2 would be the solution (though maybe the UTF-8 of the file), but that they are good practice. :)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the compiling of PCRE per this comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#103348

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use simple solution, to avoid wrong result:

```
$word='üzgün';
$article='i düzgün you ';

$match = 'nomatch';
foreach ( explode( ' ', $article ) as $w ) {
    if( $w == $word )
        $match = 'match';
}
echo $match;
```

Comment: actually my code is much more complex than the example I posted . and If I gonna leave regex then it will be hell for me :D